# Use X SSH key when logging in to Y remote user?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keygen

I'm looking for a way to set a specific SSH key while logging to a remote host with a particular username. Is this possible within the SSH config file?

For example:

Use key "id_rsa-test" for username "testuser":

```
ssh testuser@host1
ssh testuser@host2
ssh testuser@host3
```

Use key "id_rsa" for all other users.

```
ssh root@host1
ssh admin@host2
ssh user@1.2.3.4
```

Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @xhienne ([comment link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382045/use-x-ssh-key-when-logging-in-to-y-remote-user#comment678892_382047)) for your suggestion.

Adding the following to ssh_config appears to have solved the problem:

```
Match User testuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-test
```

This block should be placed above `Host *` to send `id_rsa-test` ahead of `id_rsa` for testuser.

Comment: You're welcome. You may even accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using OpenSSH you can configure your `~/.ssh/config` file for each, then you won't have to specify a user either, you can create your own name:

```
host host1
    User testuser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-test
```

then when you do `ssh host1` it will do that automatically, or, since you will use `host1` as other users too you can do

```
host test-host1
    User testuser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-test
    Hostname host1
```

then do `ssh test-host1`

and you can do the same for each host you want.

Any host that isn't matched by an entry in your ssh_config(5) file will use the default behavior--or use the defaults that are specified in ssh_config at the global setting, i.e., not inside a host block

ssh_config doesn't support matching on usernames, but you could write a shell script to detect that for you.  Here's a fragile one in bash that assumes your username/host is always the first argument and will break if it is not:

```
ssh() {
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^testuser@ ]]; then
        command ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-test "$@"
    else
        command ssh "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `host *` and / or create a rule that can match the username? Assuming there are lots of hosts, making it inefficient to create configs for each.

Comment: @user2248259 I don't know of a way to use the username as part of the pattern to match in ssh_config.  I suppose you could always try writing a shell function to check the username and add appropriate arguments as desired if no one else has a config-based answer and you don't want to have different host entries for each

Comment: @user2248259 I provided a fragile example shell function that could try to help with this situation

Comment: @Eric, you mean `ssh -i`, right? Not `ssh -I`. Moreover, in `ssh_config`, the `Match` directive allows to check against the user part.

Comment: @xhienne yes, I did mean that, and I didn't know that about the match directive!